# How do I send CSRF token authenticity from a php app that I own to a rails app that I own?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, httprequest, csrf, sugarcrm

I am an admin for a sugarCRM instance and I have a rails app on heroku. I want to be able to automatically add contacts to the rails app if they are added in sugarCRM. I have written a before_save logic_hook in my sugarCRM:

```
    function pushConts($bean, $event, $arguments)
    {
        $r = new HttpRequest('http://localhost:3000/contacts/', HttpRequest::METH_POST);
        $r->addPostFields(array('first_name' => $bean->first_name, 'last_name' => $bean->last_name, 'phone' => $bean->phone_mobile,'email' => $bean->email1, ));
        //$r->addHeaders(array('X-CSRF-Token'=> 'testing-csrf-token');
        try
        {
            echo $r->send()->getBody();
        } catch(HttpException $ex){
            SugarApplication::appendErrorMessage("<span style='color: red; font-size: 1.8em;'>Could Not Save Contact: Rails app is down.</span>");
            $queryParams = array('module' => 'Contacts', 'action' => 'ListView');
            SugarApplication::redirect('index.php?' . http_build_query($queryParams));          
        }
```

When I try to send this as it is, the console output from the rails app is:

```
Started POST "/contacts/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-06-18 15:30:14 -0500
Processing by ContactsController#create as */*
Parameters: {"first_name"=>"contact", "last_name"=>"one", "phone"=>"(555) 555-5555", "email"=>"phone.support@example.us"}
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 1ms

ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken (ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken):
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:181:in `handle_unverified_request'
actionpack (4.2.0) lib/action_controller/metal/request_forgery_protection.rb:209:in `handle_unverified_request'
devise (3.4.1) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:251:in `handle_unverified_request'

<stack trace continues>
```

I know the logic hook itself works because I tried adding  `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` to my contacts controller and then it worked as expected but for security reasons, this is not a feasible solution.

As you can see commented out, I tried sending an `X-CSRF-Token` with the headers but that didn't work either.

What can I add either to this logic hook or to my rails app itself (or both) so that I can send Http requests from my sugarCRM to my rails app without compromising (too much) security?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Rails CSRF system is not really intended to work across domains or servers. [It leverages synchronizer tokens (cryptographically random tokens) which are bound to the user's session.](https://blog.nvisium.com/2014/09/understanding-protectfromforgery.html)

Since Rails and SugarCRM do not share a user session it's impossible for Rails to validate a CSRF token from SugarCRM.

Your best bet would be to turn it off for the action with `skip_before_filter, only: [:create]`.

If you need something truly secure to verify that the request is from your SugarCRM server you would need to use something like [token based authentication](https://www.codeschool.com/blog/2014/02/03/token-based-authentication-rails/).

Many Rails based API's use a special controller and route for actions that can be performed by API clients. In your case it would look something like this:

`POST /api/v1/contacts`

```
# routes.rb
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :contacts
  end
end

# controllers/api/v1/api_controller
class ApiController < ActionController::Base
  skip_before_filter, only: [:create] 

  def authenticate
    # @todo implement token based auth
  end
end

# controllers/api/v1/contacts_controller
class Api::V1::ContactsController

  before_action :authenticate

  def create
    @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)

    # ...
  end

  # ...
end
```

Comment: So I read the token based authentication article you linked and if I understand you right, I want to send a token in the header in my HttpRequest from sugar, and then the `authenticate_or_request_with_http_token` in my rails app will receive this token from the header of the HttpRequest? But how does sugar know what the correct token is? And also, is this token based authentication a completely separate authentication mechanism? Meaning will I have to change how authentication is handled for all my controllers? Or is that what the `skip_before_filter` is there for?